# Expanding Data Validation Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I've got several data validation dropdown boxes across the top row of a spreadsheet. I'm using the following code to expand the box size (to help the users see their options) upon selecting the cell. I'm having problems getting the VBA script to ignore columns A:C upon returning the columns to normal width. These columns should be fixed at 20 and the others returned to 8.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Intersect(Target, Range("D1:AP1")) Is Nothing And Target.Columns <> "A1:C1" Then
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
     Target.Columns.ColumnWidth = 8
  Else
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
     Target.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understand well, the code shall be like:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Set xx = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D1:AP1"))
If xx Is Nothing Then
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    For i = 4 To 42
        If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 8
    Next
Else
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
    Target.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The control of the Target cor Columns A:C shall be made after.

Also I prefer to chaneg all the width for columns D:AP when you return ...
I have a little bit chaged the code... Adding the check if are Hidden, and with the line **Application.ScreenUpdating**, the code show only at the end.
I have also removed code non necessary (some if ...).

Comment: Your solution works great. One thing I've noticed is that any column which was previously Hidden becomes expanded. Is it possible to skip hidden columns? Would you create a range of Un-hidden columns or use something like:  If Target.Column > 4 AND Columns <> 0 Then ??